# Scala equivalent to pyTables?

Tags: scala, pytables

I'm looking for a little assistance in Scala similar to that provided by [pyTables](http://www.pytables.org/moin). PyTables is a package for managing hierarchical datasets and designed to efficiently and easily cope with extremely large amounts of data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It always help when you briefly describe what XXX is, or at least link to some page doing that, when you ask for an XXX feature of another language. The set of people who know Scala is much greater than the set of people who know Scala *and* Python.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder how much greater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at pyTables, and I don't think there's anything remotely like it in Scalaland (or indeed Javaland), but we have a few of the ingredients necessary to make it a possibility if you want to invest the time:

- [scala.Dynamic](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/Dynamic.html) to do idiomatic selection on data-driven structures
- A bunch of [graph databases](http://www.graph-database.org/overview.html) to provide the underlying navigational persistence substrate (I've had acceptable results from OrientDB, which has a better license than most)

Answer (score 0):

PyTables is a python implementation of HDF5 with some added niceties to let you work on it in a pythonic way, and get good indexing support. I'm not sure if there's a package implemented in a similar way in Scala, but you can use the same HFD5 based hierarchical data storageusing the HDF5 implementation in Java: [HDF Java](https://support.hdfgroup.org/products/java/)