# Scala or Java analogues of PyTables & numexpr

Tags: java, scala, bigdata, pytables, numexpr

I am looking for Scala or Java analogues of numexpr and PyTables  (particularly tables.Expr).
This is for a multicore analytics systems on multicore machines which needs to perform matrix operations over out of memory data.
In particular the libraries should optimize the movement of data between disk, ram, cache & cpu.
Sparse matrices should be handled efficiently.
For more background on what kind of issues the libraries should address see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3-oN_TulTg
and the top hits of https://www.google.com/search?q=alted+cpu+starvation.

While this question is superficially identical to [Scala equivalent to pyTables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015534/scala-equivalent-to-pytables)
that question does not specify what aspects of pytables are important and the answer there is not appropriate for my problem.

OTOH libraries dealing with cache aware & cache oblivious algorithms are likely to be of some help.

I imagine that "Scala Virtualized" (aka language virtualization) and the Stanford-PPL Delite framework
could be a good basis for building something like I need in Scala
if what I am looking for does not already exist.

Hadoop, MapReduce, graph databases & most of the popular nosql stores are not what I am looking for.
Though what I am looking for is technically a kind of nosql store.